# How do I identify frames on which the model is performing poorly for object detection?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I know there are metrics like precision and recall to evaluate how well a model is performing for object detection.

However, is there any algorithm to identify how well or how poorly a model is performing on any frame? For instance, is it possible to assign a weight to each frame in the dataset to indicate how well the model performs on that frame?

I feel this will enable more focused training, since I can assign a probability to each frame for selecting it in the next batch, kinda like AdaBoost but for object detection using CNN. This should make the model train more on frames it performs poorly on, thus improving the performance of the model.

Comment: Yes, plenty; which deep learning framework / library you are using? (Keras, TensorFlow, etc)

Comment: I am using Tensorflow. I am more interested in the algorithm irrespective of whether it is supported by the library or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you effectively seek a general 'pseudo-code', here's a script that'll work in Keras:

```py
poor_loss_threshold = 0.5
poorly_predicted = []

for x_val, y_val in data:
    loss = model.evaluate(x_val, y_val)

    if loss > poor_threshold:
        poorly_predicted.append(x_val)
```

This works for one or many 'frames' per image, as long as you fit / inference on data *iteratively* (once per loop) - so you can run checks in-between against your defined 'poorness' metric . You can then inspect each individual poor-performing frame iteratively:

```py
for x in poorly_predicted:
   plt.imshow(x) # import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: I guess I didn't frame the question accurately and should have given a bit more background. Let me update the question accordingly.

Comment: @ShreyasMundhra This doesn't change my answer; all you need to do is define your own metric (what _you_ consider to be "poor performance"); you can then collect all the data samples that the model performs poorly on. If you seek advice on the metric itself, that's a different question - if it's imbalanced classification, it could be F1-score; if multiclass classification, AUC -- see relevant [Git](https://github.com/rafaelpadilla/Object-Detection-Metrics)